# Position of arrows in Tikz

Tags: positioning, arrows, tikz-arrows

I want to draw the arrows like this picture,

[image]

but I get like this, I don't know how to position the arrows in tikz

[image]

Could you please help me?

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{box}=[draw,text width=8em, minimum height=7.5em,thin, align=flush center]
    % The comment style 
\tikzstyle{comment}=[rectangle, inner sep= 5pt, text width=4cm, node distance=0.25cm]
\tikzstyle{box1}=[draw,text width=11em, minimum height=3.5em,thin,align=flush center]
\tikzstyle{line}=[draw, thick, -latex']
        \node (1) [box] {\textbf{Customer}};
        \node (2) [box,right=30mm of 1] {\textbf{Merchant}};
        \node (3) [box1] at (3.5,-3)  {\textbf{Intermediation Server}};
        \node (4) [box1] at (3.5,-5)  {\textbf{Netbill's Bank}};
        \node (5) [box] at (0.5,-8)  {\textbf{Customer's Bank}};
        \node (6) [box] at (6.5,-8)  {\textbf{Merchant's Bank}};
        \node [comment, text width=3cm] at (1.5,-10.7)   { 1. Request quote\\
            2. Present quote\\
            3. Accept quote\\
            4. Deliver goods };

        \node [comment, text width=4cm] at (5.5,-10.9)   { 5. Send electronic payement order (EPO)\\
            6. Send EPO and key\\
            7. Send receipt\\
            8. Send receipt  };
        %arrows
         \draw [-latex,thick] (1.north) --  node[right,above] {(1)}(2.north) ;
         \draw [-latex,thick] (2) --  node[left,above] {(2)}(1) ;
          \draw [-latex,thick] (2.south west) --  node[left] {(6)}(3) ;
           \draw [-latex,thick] (3.north east) --  node[right] {(7)}(2) ;
        \draw[latex'-latex',thick]  (3) -- (4);
        \draw[latex'-latex',thick] (4.west) --  node [left] {Account funding} (5);
        \draw [-latex,thick] (4) --  node[left,below] {Batch payment}(6) ;

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `north west` and  `north east` instead of `north`. You could use the `calc` library and then `\draw [-latex,thick] ($(2.north west)+(0,-1.5em)$) --  node[above,pos=0.9] {(2)}($(1.north east)+(0,-1.5em)$) ;`, `\draw [-latex,thick] ($(1.north east)+(0,-3em)$) --  node[above,pos=0.9] {(3)}($(2.north west)+(0,-3em)$) ;` With 1.5em steps....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `|-` and `-|` to draw lines with right angles in them so, for example

```
\draw[latex'-latex',thick] (4.west) -|  node [left] {Account funding} (5);
```

will fix your funding arrow. In addition, I have tried to make the edges for `(6)` and `(7)` parallel,  I have fixed the end-points for arrow `(1)` and I have moved the arrows for `(1)` and `(2)` down a little using `yshift=-7mm` as I think this looks much nicer:

[image]

Here's the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{box}=[draw,text width=8em, minimum height=7.5em,thin, align=flush center]
    % The comment style
\tikzstyle{comment}=[rectangle, inner sep= 5pt, text width=4cm, node distance=0.25cm]
\tikzstyle{box1}=[draw,text width=11em, minimum height=3.5em,thin,align=flush center]
\tikzstyle{line}=[draw, thick, -latex']
        \node (1) [box] {\textbf{Customer}};
        \node (2) [box,right=30mm of 1] {\textbf{Merchant}};
        \node (3) [box1] at (3.5,-3)  {\textbf{Intermediation Server}};
        \node (4) [box1] at (3.5,-5)  {\textbf{Netbill's Bank}};
        \node (5) [box] at (0.5,-8)  {\textbf{Customer's Bank}};
        \node (6) [box] at (6.5,-8)  {\textbf{Merchant's Bank}};
        \node [comment, text width=3cm] at (1.5,-10.7)   { 1. Request quote\\
            2. Present quote\\
            3. Accept quote\\
            4. Deliver goods };

        \node [comment, text width=4cm] at (5.5,-10.9)   { 5. Send electronic payement order (EPO)\\
            6. Send EPO and key\\
            7. Send receipt\\
            8. Send receipt  };
        %arrows
         \draw [-latex,thick] ([yshift=-7mm]1.north east) --  node[right,above] {(1)}([yshift=-7mm]2.north west) ;
         \draw [-latex,thick] ([yshift=-7mm]2.west) --  node[left,above] {(2)}([yshift=-7mm]1.east) ;
          \draw [-latex,thick] (2.south west) --  node[left] {(6)}([xshift=5mm]3.north) ;
           \draw [-latex,thick] (3.north east) --  node[right] {(7)}(2.south) ;
        \draw[latex'-latex',thick]  (3) -- (4);
        \draw[latex'-latex',thick] (4.west) -|  node [left] {Account funding} (5);
        \draw [-latex,thick] (4) |-  node[left,below] {Batch payment}(6) ;

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You can adapt how I moved arrows`(1)` and `(2)` if you want more arrows between the "Customer" and Merchant"

By default you can use `A.north`, `A.east`, `A.south`, `A.west`, `A.north east`, ..., `A.south west` to position the end points of edges to and from node `A`. You can also use

```
\draw(A) to[out=70, in=110] (B);
```

to control the exit and entry angles for curved arrows. If you need more control over the placement of the arrows have a look at the `positioning library` -- see section 17.5.3 of the current tikz/pgf manual (page 229).

Comment: perfect thanks for the explanation, I succeed to draw the picture as I want it